# Storing Windows Updates for reuse

Tags: windows, windows-update

At work we update lots of computers using Windows Update. Windows XP and 7 all day long, rarely some Vista.

We do it through a corporate proxy, as connecting them to a domain to build a Wsus server is out of the question, so we download about two gigabytes a day of the very same updates everyday.

I've tried WSUS Offline. It's pretty complete but when it finishes it's common to be still missing hundreds of megabytes of updates, because its intention is not to fully update a system but to install the critical updates, as the developers explain in the forums.

Now I'm trying with Autoupdater. It's far worse, with poor capabilities for non-English Windows XP, but at least it gives the option to install non critical updates in Windows 7. It still misses hundres of megabytes of updates after fully updating the system.

And finally, both doesn't install the driver related updates of Windows 7, so they at most save us a couple of hundreds of megabytes and a reboot (with the associated login to the computer and to the proxy) out of three or four.

So, is it possible to somewhat extract the installed updates in a Windows 7 system and not having to download the same updates again and again at least with machines with the same hardware? Or even better, a generic package with all the updates?

Comment: Why aren't you deploying a proper [WSUS role](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services) in your network?

Comment: To my knowlege all security patches are offered in a stand-alone form on the Microsoft website.  It seems that creating your own WSUS server would be much easier.  Why do you care if your download 2GB that is nothing in today's world.

Comment: WSUS doesn't care whether the clients are in a domain or not, so it would be a reasonable option, particularly if combined with a script to do the installs.  This might be a useful starting point: http://www.scms.waikato.ac.nz/~harry/wsusupdate.vbs

Comment: A better option might be to simply use a proxy server to cache the updates for you.  A transparent proxy would be particularly convenient since you wouldn't then need to reconfigure the clients, just plug them into the right network segment.

Answer (score 1):

[Offline Update](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-download-windows-updates-for-offline-windows-update/)  is a program that can download all the relevant updates (it has a few options including yes/no service packs, yes/no .Net framework updates and more) and the store them in a variety of formats (inlcuding .iso).

You can then make as many copies of those files as you want locally.

Comment: That's the old name for WSUS Offline Update, sadly its developers and I have different opinions about that is a relevant update.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make a proxy for that, the one that can store files and serve them later. If you are familiar with python you can try this one: http://code.google.com/p/samesite/

I'm occasionaly commiting patches to this one. Feel free to file bugs... :)

Comment: Couldn't make it work in archlinux, because of missing libraries even if they are installed. With ubuntu, and after adding your library py-spacemap to the same directory, it says it's missing the config file. Adding an empty file named samesite.conf does the trick.

Comment: Nope, it still fails. You should provide a sample config file.

Comment: I've commited one.